# Manipulating a .csv file to look for two common values to create a key, then summing up values

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x, csv

My code reads a .csv file, looks for a couple values to create its key, and then wraps up the data based on a few business rules I have. I'm trying to learn "the right way", so I'd really appreciate some tips and hints.

```
import csv
import sys

# add DictReader
with open(sys.argv[1], 'rbU') as csvinfile:
    myreader = csv.reader(csvinfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

    # initialize variables and dictionaries
    line_cntr = 0
    dict = {}
    cntr = {}

    for row in myreader:
        # constant values
        nd_amt = row[14]
        deduct_amt = row[15]
        nondeduct_ytd = row[16]
        deduct_ytd = row[17]
        pid = row[18]
        don_date = row[19]
        amount = row[23]
        anon = row[25]
        int_0003 = row[38]
        int_0006 = row[39]
        int_0028 = row[40]

        # create a composite key for our dictionary
        key = pid + ":" + don_date
        # check to see if key exists in dictionary, if not then add
        # as per BR-0010 every group of up to 6 entries with same P_ID and Don_Date should print on their own line (i.e. different entry in Dict).  
        if key in dict:
            if cntr[key] % 6 != 0:
                dict[key][14] += row[14]
                dict[key][15] += row[15]
                dict[key][16] += row[16]
                dict[key][17] += row[17]
                dict[key][23] += row[23]
                cntr[key] += 1
            else:
                key = pid + ":" + don_date + ":" + str(cntr[key]//6)
                dict[key] = row
        else:
            dict[key] = row
            cntr[key] = 1

        # debugging
        for key in cntr:
            if cntr[key] > 6:
                print(key, cntr[key])

        # keep track of lines processed for recon
        line_cntr += 1

# add DictWriter        
with open(sys.argv[2], 'wb') as csvoutfile:
    mywriter = csv.writer(csvoutfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

    for key in dict:
        outline = (key, dict[key])
        mywriter.writerow(outline)

    # print recon totals at bottom
    csvoutfile.write("Total lines processed: " + str(line_cntr))
```

I have some comments in there about wanting to try out `DictReader`/`DictWriter` in my next draft of code, so if anyone has tips on that it would be much appreciated as well.

Answer (score 3):

Overall, your code is pretty clean.

Here are some points for improvement:

- Use the if `__name__ == '__main__'` idiom if this file is to be executed directly. [https://docs.python.org/2/library/**main**.html](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__main__.html)
- Structure your code so that no code is executed before the **name** clause or upon import. In other words, don't have any code blocks which start at the left-hand margin. Instead, place code within a few functions which are called by a main `run()` function.
- Use an `enum` or constants to represent the index values for things like nd_amount.

EDIT

```
ND_AMT = 14
...

nd_amt = row[ND_AMT]
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I actually knew that, not sure why I didn't implement it:) I normally call my main function main(), I have added that in now.  As for your last point, can you elaborate a little further?  Should I have my index values included in my dictionary?

Comment: Sure thing! See my edit. This change allows for reuse of the constants in other portions of the code and mitigates the risk of bugs from incorrect integer values.

Comment: Oh gotcha, that makes a ton of sense!

Comment: I've updated my code, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Looks good, though you still have a variable named 'dict' which is a reserved word in python (as others have pointed out).

Comment: I had new code in but I guess that is against the rules so what you saw was my original code:)  I'll be posting a new question with my updated code.

Answer (score 3):

When iterating over the entries of a dictionary,
it's more efficient to iterate over the items.
So instead of this:

> ```
> for key in dict:
>     outline = (key, dict[key])
>     mywriter.writerow(outline)
> ```

This is more efficient, because it avoids the dictionary lookup `dict[key]`:

```
for key, value in dict.items():
    outline = (key, value)
    mywriter.writerow(outline)
```

---

Instead of magic numbers like these:

> ```
> dict[key][14] += row[14]
> dict[key][15] += row[15]
> dict[key][16] += row[16]
> dict[key][17] += row[17]
> dict[key][23] += row[23]
> ```

It would be better to define variables like `COL_ND_AMT`, `COL_DEDUCT_AMT`, `COL_NONDEDUCT_YTD`, and so on.
That way it will be more readable what's going on,
and if the columns get reordered,
you will be able to change the numbering in one place.

---

Instead of using `sys.argv`, you might benefit from [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html),
a very powerful yet easy to use command line argument parsing package (included with modern versions of Python).

Answer (score 3):

- `dict` is a reserved keyword, don't name anything that! If you can't think of a more descriptive name, PEP8 recommends `dict_`
- What's the point in assigning a bunch of items in `row` to concrete variables, if you later don't use them? I think the best approach is to get rid of the variables, and turn your accumulkation logic into something like:

  ```
  if key in dict_:
      if cntr[key] % 6:  # don't need the '!= 0'
          for index in (14, 15, 16, 17, 23):
              dict_[key][index] += row[index]
      else:
  ```
- I also don't like much the way you are dealing with groups of more than 6 repeated entries. It may force you to do changes elsewhere, but why not store a list and append new groups to it?

  ```
  for row in myreader:
      pid = row[18]
      don_date = row[19]
      key = ':'.join((pid, don_date))

      store = dict_.setdefault(key, [])
      counts = cntr.get(key, 0)
      if counts % 6:
          for index in (14, 15, 16, 17, 23):
              store[-1][index] += row[index]
      else:
          store.append(row)
      cntr[key] += 1
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, you make some great points!  I'm going to walk through your logic when I get a chance and might have some more questions for you!

Comment: <pedantic> If `dict` were a reserved keyword, the OP *couldn't* use it as a name..

Comment: You are absolutely right, `dict` is [not really a keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9642137/110026), just a name taken by a very popular standard library class. It still doesn't make it a good practice to shadow it, but that is a different discussion.

Comment: @Jaime Would you mind explaining what you're doing with the lists a little more?  I understand some of it, but I'm getting confused with what you're doing with the lists.  Are you using lists instead of dictionary entries?

Comment: Instead of making new keys by appending numbers to it, the key is kept as is, but the corresponding value is a list. New data is appended to the last element of the list, unless it's the 1st, 7th, 13th... in which cases a new item is appended to the list.